# What are the responsibilities of a junior developer?

Tags: developer, junior, corporate-responsibility

I would like to ask the following questions. What are the responsibilities of a junior developer? Will he/she be given a task to develop a new project from the start without any supervision? What if he/she gets stuck and can't find any solution? If that was happening to me, I would be in panic mode! Also how about training?

Comment: Is your questions how you should onboard a junior developer or what to expect as a junior developer. Your title isn't a questions or a sentence.

If you are starting a new job its kind of impossible for us to know the detail of how that company runs itself.

Comment: If you can't find a solution, then ask? You have the ability to communicate. Nobody expects a junior to be an expert otherwise you'd be a senior and even then seniors ask for help.

Comment: @Twyxz I don't think asking questions will look good on the junior position's side.

Comment: @Theo It looks a lot better than doing 0 work because you couldn't ask for help

Comment: @Theo What so the junior should just never ask for help and not improve and just fail in his career because he failed to ask a simple question that would help him finish his project?

Comment: Software engineeing is notoriously "self-starting".  The fact is you will get far less guidance than in any other field.

Comment: The first responsibility of a junior engineer is to become an engineer. That means you learn. That means you ask questions - ideally after some research, though some questions are not researchable.

Comment: @Twyxz You are missing a very important point. A junior developer has more than 90% chances to fail his probationary period and get fired. the only way to survive is to sit down work really hard and solve all the challenges by yourself. That's how it works. If you get stuck that's it. People from HR or other departments will think you are stupid and suddenly everyone will laugh at you.  There is no such thing as training. It costs time and money.

Comment: @Theo sounds like the places you worked at so far are extremely harsh and should be avoided at all costs. not allowing junior devs to ask questions is a HUGE red flag

Comment: @Mark It's not that I was not allowed to ask questions(they were annoyed though and they were laughing at me), but the Google API I was using for the native Android app(Google Fit) was not working in Samsung S5 and upwards. Even Google itself couldn't fix it after sending them lots of bug reports. I got no help on that at all. The are cases where you will fail no matter how intelligent and good you are!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Varies a lot by company but generally at the start you will get very simple tasks with offer of support from your direct senior dev. However this will usually ramp up fairly quickly and by 2 months in you'll be expected to be working fairly independently and not having to ask for help much. You'll just be kept away from very sensitive and complex areas of code most likely. Having a start/finish project after an initial month or 2 isn't hard to imagine.

Answer (score 1):

It's up to the company, and it can vary.    But typically, a junior developer is given tasks suitable to a less experienced developer.  It MIGHT be a start-to-finish project, but more than likely I'd guess it would be as a team member, under the supervision of a senior developer/team leader.   Most companies allow said developer to get familiar with the company and codebase before expecting much.